# ajax requests when navigating in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser

I have a web page which perform several ajax request and is modified, all ajax request are cached on the page. Then user clicks some link and performs the synchronous request to another page. Then user clicks "back" button of the browser. All data which was previously loaded via ajax is lost. Is it possible to restore the page state after user clicks "back" button in the browser, so all data previously loaded is restored without new ajax requests ?

The jQuery history plugin gives a little help, it allows to get back to the correct point of the page, but it performs necessary ajax requests. Additionaly if there are many ajax requests it is difficult to store them in the history correctly.

Is there a way to solve my problem without using cookies or server side ?

Comment: Without using the history, it's going to be very complicated. Otherwise, you'd have to pushState() with information about the current state. Cookies are probably not a good idea in this case though. Saving in a session on the server is a pretty good solution, however, when the user comes back to that page a few days later, he's not unlikely to see exactly what he had before which may not be what you want...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to solve my problem
>   without using cookies or server side ?

The answer is likely 'no'. The data used for JS is driven by what is given from the server.  In order to save the information, you will need to store it on the server and send it back.

The notion of strictly using JS will tie your hands unnecessarily. Saving this stuff to a session variable during the AJAX call to the server (since it's communicating with the server anyways) will likely be a fairly straightforward implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Really Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) gives a very flexible API to manage the functionality of the back button.

Comment: I don't think that history allows to restore loaded ajax data.